# Based on the value of a session variable hide a child menu item in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, menu, menuitem

How do I add a child item to a asp:Menu based on the value of a session variable?

I don't have a clue how to do this and I've searched the internet for over an hour. Here is my shot at something that doesn't work

```
Dim valuePath2 As String = "RESULTS|8 Hr - TEC 375 - DCs|TTB"

If Session("svUser") = "udaljrb" Or Session("svUser") = "yoiddl" 
                                 Or Session("svUser") = "yoijkb" 
                                 Or Session("svUser") = "uyrf73f" Then

    VitalSignsMainMenu.FindItem(valuePath2)
    VitalSignsMainMenu.Items.Add(VitalSignsMainMenu.FindItem(valuePath))
End If
```

I can remove items but only on the root level, it just seems to ignore me if I set the value path to go any deeper

Here's what I do for this:

```
Dim valuePath As String = "RESULTS|8 Hr - TEC 375 - DCs|TTB"

If Session("svUser") = "uyrf73f" Then
    VitalSignsMainMenu.Items.Remove(VitalSignsMainMenu.FindItem(valuePath))
End If
```

I changed the path separator to | instead of , and it didn't matter. I debugged it and it runs the Remove statement or it give me a "Value cannot be null" error,  but the menu item is still there.

C'mon Microsoft why is this so difficult?

The menu in the aspx huge, this menu is humongous so I will post only the relavant items

Comment: Can you post your ASPX markup? Also under which method are you executing the first fragment of code?

Comment: I tried but its not showing up I suppose I need to get into the forum code and start researching

Answer (score 0):

with this code you can add a child in menuItem.

menu1 is a object menuItem, menuTest is a menuItem of menu1.

example:

```
 Dim menuTest = New MenuItem()
 menuTest.Text = "something"
 menuTest.NavigateUrl = "something"
 menuTest.Value = "something"
 menu1.Items.Add(menuTest)

now add the child to Menu1:

 Dim child = New MenuItem()
 child.Text = "something"
 child.NavigateUrl = "something"
 child.Value = "something"
 menuTest.ChildItems.Add(child)
```

Regards.

Comment: How does the program know which parent element to add the child menu item to?

Comment: I was able to add a "child" element but it just added it to the root level, its not much of a child element if I can't put it under a parent item

Comment: you must specify... 
parentToAddToMenu.Items.Add(YOURMENUITEM) 
for the child:
parent.childItems.add(YOURCHILD)

Comment: hmm maybe the question is too hard to understand, lets simplify it. 1. I need to be able to remove a CHILD menu item based on a session variable
2. I need to be able to add a CHILD element UNDER an existing PARENT MenuItem.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a property in the MenuItem called "Visible" and a handle to grab and then you could simply set visible to true or false, guess I'm smarter than Microsoft

Comment: Please edit your existing code for your answers if the answer is not correct